# ¿Cómo se crean los sinónimos de etiquetas?

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Me gustaría saber cómo se crean los sinónimos de etiquetas, he estado buscando cómo hacerlo pero no lo encuentro.

¿Se debe hacer a través de meta sugiriendo el sinónimo y que algún admin lo cree o hay otra forma?

Comment: Has revisado este link de ayuda http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms ?

Comment: Muchas gracias, no encontraba el link de la ayuda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.- Dale a la etiqueta a la que quieras añadir el sinónimo y después al enlace de sinónimos que se encuentra justo debajo de su descripción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Una vez allí dirígete al apartado `Sugerir un sinónimo de [etiqueta]` y dale al botón de enviar.

Nótese que puedes sugerirla si tienes el privilegio [Crear sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) y un mínimo de reputación de 5 puntos en esa etiqueta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde entonces tu sugerencia estará expuesta a una votación en [Sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) y de ella dependerá si se crea el sinónimo que acabas de sugerir o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y por los pasos, no encontraba el link de la ayuda

Comment: A mí me dice que necesito 5 votos para sugerir un sinónimo de datatables, pero tengo más que eso, a mi entender