# Hacer la etiqueta mssql sinónimo de SQL-Server

Tags: discusión, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

[He propuesto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms) la creación del sinónimo [mssql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mssql) para la etiqueta [sql-server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server).

Si bien la etiqueta [mssql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mssql) dice en su descripción:

> Controlador cliente de Microsoft SQL para `node.js`. Usar esta etiqueta en preguntas relacionadas con dicho cliente (`npm mssql`)

Ocurre lo siguiente:

- No tiene un wiki de etiqueta,
- En la práctica se está usando para preguntas relacionadas con el motor
- En StackOverflow en inglés es sinónimo de sql-server

Solicito a los usuarios con suficiente reputación votar a favor de este **en el siguiente enlace**

https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms

También, algún experto de [node-js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-js) podría ayudarnos a identificar la etiqueta adecuada para el cliente de Microsoft SQL para dicha plataforma (si es que es necesaria) y crearla.

Si dejan una respuesta o comentario aquí, yo ayudo a identificar y *migrar* las pocas preguntas que realmente correspondan a dicha etiqueta entre las que actualmente usan [mssql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mssql).

**Edición:** Edité la pregunta para aclarar que se vota por el sinónimo [en el enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms) y no (solamente) aquí en la publicación en Meta. Más información en [cómo se crean los sinónimos de etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1192/21), aquí en meta.

Comment: caemos en un problema: sql-server es el nombre del programa o software comercial, mssql es el nombre del empaquetado de distribucion del software.

Comment: Entiendo que en el ienguaje diario pueden ser cosas distintas, pero hablamos de etiquetas del sitio y ek términos prácticos, ¿Qué preguntas pertenecerían a una que no pertenezcan a la otra etiqueta? O ¿por qué nos conviene mantenerlas y quién sería responsable de mover preguntas de la una a la.otra? Porque viendo las preguntas de hoy, pareciera que la comunidad no hace la diferencia.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, deberían ser sinónimos, no aportan nada por separado.

Comment: yo creo que deberiamos de eliminar mssql ... y evangelizar a los usuarios explicandoles que el termino correcto es: [sql-server]

Comment: Es el efecto que tiene convertirla en un sinónimo, sin la necesidad de _evangelizar_ a nadie. Por eso mi propuesta.