# ¿Podemos hacer [gcloud] y [gcp] sinónimos de [google-cloud-platform]?

Tags: discusión, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Actualmente hay:

- 11 Preguntas con la etiqueta [gcloud](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcloud)
- 14 Preguntas con la etiqueta [gcp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcp)
- 97 Preguntas con la etiqueta [google-cloud-platform](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform)

Mi pregunta es:

Si [gcloud](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcloud) y [gcp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcp) **hacen referencia la misma plataforma (Google Cloud Platform)**, ¿Por qué no hacerlos sinónimos? Para respaldar mi afirmación, veo que **en StackOverflow (en inglés), las etiquetas [gcp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcp) y [google-cloud-platform](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) son sinónimos.**

Comment: Me parece bien, no soy usuario de dichas etiquetas por lo que no puedo directamente [sugerir la creación del sinónimo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1193/21). Si tú lo eres, sugiero que lo hagas para que otros usuarios puedan votar por el sinónimo y que quede.

Comment: De acuerdo contigo, como comentas, en el sitio en inglés [gpc] es sinónimo de  [google-cloud-platform] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcp

Comment: @Jorgesys Perfecto. El problema es que no tengo la puntuación suficiente para sugerir un sinónimo de etiqueta, pero quisiera ayudar a la comunidad a evitar tener múltiples etiquetas que significan lo mismo.